# What needs to be done in controller for autosave child object in has_one autosave: true?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Rails has_one relationship with `autosave: true`, do we need to generate child object in create and set params to allow mass_assignment of child object if we want child object is saved along with its parent object?

For example, a `customer` has_one `address`:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :address, autosave: true
end
```

In `customers` controller, noticed that `address` object has been built:

```
def new
  customer = Customer.new
  customer.build_address
end
```

Here is our question: in `create`, is the following code enough to save `address` along with `customer` magically (assuming there are fields for `address` on `customer` views)?

```
def create
  customer = Customer.new(new_params)
  if customer.save  #is `address` saved along with `customer` magically?
     redirect_to ...
  end
end
```

Or if the code above can not accomplish that, what else we need to do to autosave `address` (such as generating `address` object or/and set params for mass_assignment of `address` object in `customers` controller)?

Comment: Your current code is correct to save address along with customer.

Comment: `@Pavan`, good to know. Is the autosave like a blind save, even without specifying mass-assigment attributes in child object? With accepts_nested_attribues_for, the nested attributes have to be explicitly spelled out in parent controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to assign attributes to address as well before saving customer.

```
e.g. customer.address.landmark = "sony center"
```

refer this http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AutosaveAssociation.html

alternatively you can use `nested_attributes`
 refer this http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Comment: Certainly we need to put fields for address on cusomer's form with fields_for. But nested attributes is not working for us, as it requires spell out child attributes in parent's controller for mass_assignment.

Comment: `will need to assign attributes to address` - true!